# How to whitelist IP addresses in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql

Trying to follow this guide (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc) to send Google Form responses to a local MySQL server. I have no idea how to whitelist IP addresses inside MySQL Workbench. I already tried googling, and going through the workbench documentation, but can't find anything.

How do I whitelist IP addresses that can connect to my local MySQL database in Workbench? This is MySQL 5.7.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I work in a lab where we do a lot of next-generation sequencing. When we publish our work, we generally have to submit a lot of metadata along with these datasets, so I wanted to create a Google Form that anyone in our lab can fill out to collect this metadata information, and then automatically save the metadata to a local MySQL database for easy access after I leave.

EDIT: Added the link to the guide I talked about.

Comment: Does local mean, that the database runs locally on your computer? The problem here would be, that you need to open a port in the firewall of your local network. Besides that if you haven't a static ip, your ip address will change regularly. I would recommend to use a database, which runs online on a server.

Comment: Yes, local means locally on a computer. I see, it sounds like it may be more trouble that it's worth. Maybe it's worth shelling out for a Google SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish this is through the Users and Privileges options menu, which can be accessed through the Server dropdown in MySQL Workbench. Through this menu you will be able to set the allowed host for a given user who can be configured to have whatever type of database access you need.

See link for more info https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-mysql-connections-navigator-management-users-and-privileges.html